# Keep label element prevents my search bar corners from rounding?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

## Problem

If I keep my label element (and from what I've read, every `input` element should have a label element, even if you're not using it, for disabled users), my search box corners on the left-hand side aren't being rounded.

Also, you can tell (if you look close enough) that my search button on the right side isn't aligning perfectly with the rest of the search bar.

Delete the entire `label` element, and it looks perfectly fine. However, I want to make sure I am practicing good coding manners/behaviors.

How can I make my search bar look the way it looks when you delete the `label` element, while still using the `label` element?

## Troubleshooting

- I have tried using CSS to style the entire bar, to no avail.
- I have tried placing the `input` element, the `button` element, and the
  `span` element inside of the `label` element to no avail.

## My Code

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/12o0xafr/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see bootstrap targeting class names based on first or last child.

```
.input-group .form-control:not(:first-child):not(:last-child), .input-group-addon:not(:first-child):not(:last-child), .input-group-btn:not(:first-child):not(:last-child)
```

and

```
.input-group .form-control:not(:first-child):not(:last-child), .input-group-addon:not(:first-child):not(:last-child), .input-group-btn:not(:first-child):not(:last-child)
```

which appear to be in the _border-radius.scss. Im not totally sure why they are doing this but I did see that is was what was needed to add the border. So basically, the element you needed to have a border-radius, only receives those styles if its the first element.

Just switch:

  `<input class="form-control" id="search-bar" placeholder="This bar has rounded corners only on the right side.">
<label for="search-bar" class="sr-only"></label>`

Comment: Well that was a quick fix. Could you sort of explain the part where you mention how the class names are targeting the first or last child? This fixed my issue, but I am not sure HOW, which is what I would like to know as well. :)

Comment: added more info. Hope that helped.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly use below css to apply left rounded corner.

```
#search-bar{
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
}
```